# jquery validator - http | https | ftp | www

Tags: jquery, validation

see http://jsfiddle.net/gVVa8/7/

I'm trying to validate http | https | ftp | www.  But can't seem to get it to validate https URLs.

Can anyone help?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 // Validates  http | https | ftp
 // http://www.cnn.com  | https://www.facebook.com  | ftp://myurl.com  | www.igs.org

    $.validator.addMethod("cus_url", function (value, element) {
        if (value.substr(0, 7) != 'http://') {
            value = 'http://' + value;         
        }

        if (value.substr(value.length - 1, 1) != '/') {
            value = value + '/';
        }

        return this.optional(element) || /^(https|http):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(value);
    }, "Not valid url.");

    $("#myform").validate({
        ignore: [],
    });

});
```

Comment: The first couple lines of your function will turn `https://example.com` into `http://https://example.com` which won't pass your validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `&& value.substr(0, 8) != 'https://'` to your code ,like :

```
$.validator.addMethod("cus_url", function (value, element) {
    if (value.substr(0, 7) != 'http://' && value.substr(0, 8) != 'https://') {
        value = 'http://' + value;         
    }
```

or use regex like: `if (!value.match(/^http(s?):\/\//))`
otherwise your `https://www.facebook.com` will become `http://https://www.facebook.com`